# ShowWindow vs SWP_SHOWWINDOW vs WS_VISIBLE

Tags: winapi

What is the difference between the following methods of showing a window:

- The **`ShowWindow`** function.
- The **`SetWindowPos`** function with the **`SWP_SHOWWINDOW`** flag.
- The **`SetWindowLong`** function with **`WS_VISIBLE`** added to **`GWL_STYLE`**.

Are there any other methods?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to write a program that monitors other programs' activity, and I need to know when a window is shown. I thought about achieving it with API hooking, but now I'm considering using a message hook and monitoring WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED messages.
Do you know whether a window always receives the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message when shown?

Comment: Why didn't you ask that question? That's what you want to know. Ask it directly. And yes, windows are notified when their visibility changes.

Comment: Looks like you're attacking me for no reason. I ask whatever question I want, dude.
I've asked a question that interested me, and might also interest others. I didn't find a direct answer to it on the internet.
rodrigo provided me with a good answer, also mentioning `DeferWindowPos`, which might come in handy.

Comment: I'm not attacking you. If you want to know whether or not `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is always sent, you should ask that. The question you appears to be unrelated.

Comment: Use the accessibility functions to monitor windows being shown and hidden. That's what they're for.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those. Do you mean `SetWinEventHook` and friends?

Comment: [Yes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx). Note also that modifying the style bits directly bypasses the normal bookkeeping. It's the equivalent of [prank-calling a window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/24/10421022.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that they are mostly the same, but with additional capabilities for each one:

1. `SetWindowLong` with `WS_VISIBLE` added to `GWL_STYLE` is proably the least interesting: why mess with style bits if there is a function that does exactly what you need.
2. `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` allows you to show the window and set its location and size at the same time, with a single atomic operation, so that no-one - program or user - may see the visible-unmoved or moved-invisible window.
3. The `ShowWindow` function has a lot of magic involved, particularly the very first time it is called in a program. Additionaly, it has the `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` flag that is little used but not available to any other method, AFAIK.

There are other  ways to make a window visible. From the top of my mind:

1. Create it with the `WS_VISIBLE` flag set.
2. `DeferWindowPos` has the same flags than `SetWindowPos`.

Answer (score 2):

The `SetWindowLong` function sets the initial window style, i.e. if the window will appear immediately or not after creation. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that after window creation, you have to use the other two functions to set the visible property. A typical use would be:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    long style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style | WS_DLGFRAME);

    return 0;
}
```

`ShowWindow` and `SetWindowPos` have an overlapping functionality regarding the window visibility. If you have to move the window in x, y or z direction at the same time as setting its visibility, use `SetWindowPos`. I personally find that the need to specify the necessary uFlags parameter makes this function a bit cumbersome to use, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your friend ;-)

If on the other hand you don't need the window to move at all but are about to maximize, minimize, restore etc. it, use `ShowWindow`. Since it only takes the window handle and the nCmdShow constant as parameters, it's an easy-to-use function.